# How do I pass a savepoint to Flink when running a job from the IDE

Tags: apache-flink

I want to start a job in my IDE from a savepoint. How do I pass a savepoint to Flink.

I tried the following code, but it didn't work

```java
StreamGraph streamGraph = env.getStreamGraph();
streamGraph.setSavepointRestoreSettings(SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath("myPath"));
env.executeAsync(streamGraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

The savepoint restore settings get overridden in by the local executor. This works:

```java
Configuration config = new Configuration();
if (savepointLocation != null) {
    config.set(SavepointConfigOptions.SAVEPOINT_PATH, savepointLocation);
}
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(config);
```